# "The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly..." exception in SSDT

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

In our VStudio 2015 solution we have a series of SSDT's. One of them is returning the exception **"The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly. Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.BuildFailedException: An entry with the same key already exists."**. I went into the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets and took a look at the  (posting it below)

```
<SqlBuildTask   PostdeployItem="@(PostDeploy->'%(FullPath)')"
      PredeployItem="@(PreDeploy->'%(FullPath)')"
      RefactorLog="@(RefactorLog->'%(FullPath)')"
      SqlTarget="@(SqlTarget)"

      ContributorArguments="$(ContributorArguments)"

      BuildExtensionConfiguration="@(BuildExtensionConfiguration)"
      BuildContributors="$(BuildContributors)"
      DeploymentExtensionConfiguration="@(DeploymentExtensionConfiguration)"
      DeploymentContributors="$(DeploymentContributors)"

      ConnectionString="$(TargetConnectionString)"
      CreateScriptFileName="$(CreateScriptFileName)"
      DacApplicationName="$(DacApplicationName)"
      DacDescription="$(DacDescription)"
      DacFile="@(DacFile)"
      DacVersion="$(DacVersion)"
      DatabaseName="$(TargetDatabase)"
      DatabaseSchemaProviderName="$(DSP)"
      DefaultSchema="$(DefaultSchema)"
      DeploymentScriptName="$(DeployScriptFileName)"
      DeployToDatabase="$(UpdateDatabase)"
      GenerateCreateScript="$(GenerateCreateScript)"
      GenerateDac="$(GenerateDac)"
      ImplicitDllAssemblyName="$(AssemblyName)"
      ImplicitDllAssemblyOwner="$(AssemblyOwner)"
      ImplicitDllFileName="$(IntermediateTargetFullFileName)"
      ImplicitDllSymbolsFileName="$(IntermediateSymbolsFullFileName)"
      ImplicitDllGenerateSqlClrDdl="$(GenerateSqlClrDdl)"
      ImplicitDllIsVisible="$(IsVisible)"
      ImplicitDllPermissionSet="$(PermissionSet)"
      IntermediateDirectory="$(GeneratedFilesIntermediatePath)"
      ModelCollation="$(ModelCollation)"
      OutputDirectory="$(TargetDir)"
      PreserveHeaderComments="$(PreserveHeaderComments)"
      Source="@(Build->'%(FullPath)')"
      SqlCmdVariables="@(SqlCmdVariables)"
      SqlReferencePath="@(SqlReferencePath)"
      SuppressTSqlWarnings="$(SuppressTSqlWarnings)"
      TreatTSqlWarningsAsErrors="$(TreatTSqlWarningsAsErrors)"
      ValidateCasingOnIdentifiers="$(ValidateCasingOnIdentifiers)"
      CmdLineInMemoryStorage="$(CmdLineInMemoryStorage)"
      DefaultCollation="$(DefaultCollation)"
      AnsiNullDefault="$(AnsiNullDefault)"
      AnsiNulls="$(AnsiNulls)"
      AnsiPadding="$(AnsiPadding)"
      AnsiWarnings="$(AnsiWarnings)"
      ArithAbort="$(ArithAbort)"
      ConcatNullYieldsNull="$(ConcatNullYieldsNull)"
      QuotedIdentifier="$(QuotedIdentifier)"
      NumericRoundAbort="$(NumericRoundAbort)"
      RecursiveTriggersEnabled="$(RecursiveTriggersEnabled)"
      DatabaseChaining="$(DatabaseChaining)"
      DatabaseState="$(DatabaseState)"
      UpdateOptions="$(UpdateOptions)"
      CloseCursorOnCommitEnabled="$(CloseCursorOnCommitEnabled)"
      DefaultCursor="$(DefaultCursor)"
      AutoClose="$(AutoClose)"
      AutoCreateStatistics="$(AutoCreateStatistics)"
      AutoShrink="$(AutoShrink)"
      AutoUpdateStatistics="$(AutoUpdateStatistics)"
      TornPageDetection="$(TornPageDetection)"
      DatabaseAccess="$(DatabaseAccess)"
      Recovery="$(Recovery)"
      EnableFullTextSearch="$(EnableFullTextSearch)"
      DefaultFilegroup="$(DefaultFilegroup)"
      Trustworthy="$(Trustworthy)"
      AutoUpdateStatisticsAsynchronously="$(AutoUpdateStatisticsAsynchronously)"
      PageVerify="$(PageVerify)"
      ServiceBrokerOption="$(ServiceBrokerOption)"
      DateCorrelationOptimizationOn="$(DateCorrelationOptimizationOn)"
      Parameterization="$(Parameterization)"
      AllowSnapshotIsolation="$(AllowSnapshotIsolation)"
      ReadCommittedSnapshot="$(ReadCommittedSnapshot)"
      VardecimalStorageFormatOn="$(VardecimalStorageFormatOn)"
      SupplementalLoggingOn="$(SupplementalLoggingOn)"
      CompatibilityMode="$(CompatibilityMode)"
      DefaultFileStreamFilegroup="$(DefaultFileStreamFilegroup)"
      IsChangeTrackingOn="$(IsChangeTrackingOn)"
      IsChangeTrackingAutoCleanupOn="$(IsChangeTrackingAutoCleanupOn)"
      ChangeTrackingRetentionPeriod="$(ChangeTrackingRetentionPeriod)"
      ChangeTrackingRetentionUnit="$(ChangeTrackingRetentionUnit)"
      IsEncryptionOn="$(IsEncryptionOn)"
      IsBrokerPriorityHonored="$(IsBrokerPriorityHonored)"
      Containment="$(Containment)"
      DatabaseDefaultLanguage="$(DatabaseDefaultLanguage)"
      DatabaseDefaultFulltextLanguage="$(DatabaseDefaultFulltextLanguage)"
      IsNestedTriggersOn="$(IsNestedTriggersOn)"
      IsTransformNoiseWordsOn="$(IsTransformNoiseWordsOn)"
      TwoDigitYearCutoff="$(TwoDigitYearCutoff)"
      NonTransactedFileStreamAccess="$(NonTransactedFileStreamAccess)"
      FileStreamDirectoryName="$(FileStreamDirectoryName)"
      TargetRecoveryTimePeriod="$(TargetRecoveryTimePeriod)"
      TargetRecoveryTimeUnit="$(TargetRecoveryTimeUnit)"
      DelayedDurability="$(DelayedDurability)"
      AutoCreateStatisticsIncremental="$(AutoCreateStatisticsIncremental)"
      MemoryOptimizedElevateToSnapshot="$(MemoryOptimizedElevateToSnapshot)"
      QueryStoreCaptureMode="$(QueryStoreCaptureMode)"
      QueryStoreDesiredState="$(QueryStoreDesiredState)"
      QueryStoreFlushInterval="$(QueryStoreFlushInterval)"
      QueryStoreStatsInterval="$(QueryStoreStatsInterval)"
      QueryStoreMaxPlansPerQuery="$(QueryStoreMaxPlansPerQuery)"
      QueryStoreStaleQueryThreshold="$(QueryStoreStaleQueryThreshold)"
      QueryStoreMaxStorageSize="$(QueryStoreMaxStorageSize)"
      DbScopedConfigLegacyCardinalityEstimation="$(DbScopedConfigLegacyCardinalityEstimation)"
      DbScopedConfigLegacyCardinalityEstimationSecondary="$(DbScopedConfigLegacyCardinalityEstimationSecondary)"
      DbScopedConfigMaxDOP="$(DbScopedConfigMaxDOP)"
      DbScopedConfigMaxDOPSecondary="$(DbScopedConfigMaxDOPSecondary)"
      DbScopedConfigParameterSniffing="$(DbScopedConfigParameterSniffing)"
      DbScopedConfigParameterSniffingSecondary="$(DbScopedConfigParameterSniffingSecondary)"
      DbScopedConfigOptimizerHotfixes="$(DbScopedConfigOptimizerHotfixes)"
      DbScopedConfigOptimizerHotfixesSecondary="$(DbScopedConfigOptimizerHotfixesSecondary)"
      TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled="$(TemporalHistoryRetentionEnabled)"
      AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="$(AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments)"
      AdditionalDeploymentContributors="$(AdditionalDeploymentContributors)"
      AllowDropBlockingAssemblies="$(AllowDropBlockingAssemblies)"
      AllowIncompatiblePlatform="$(AllowIncompatiblePlatform)"
      AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement="$(AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement)"
      BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges="$(BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges)"
      BlockOnPossibleDataLoss="$(BlockOnPossibleDataLoss)"
      BlockWhenDriftDetected="$(BlockWhenDriftDetected)"
      CommentOutSetVarDeclarations="$(CommentOutSetVarDeclarations)"
      CompareUsingTargetCollation="$(CompareUsingTargetCollation)"
      CreateNewDatabase="$(CreateNewDatabase)"
      DeployDatabaseInSingleUserMode="$(DeployDatabaseInSingleUserMode)"
      DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers="$(DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers)"
      DoNotAlterChangeDataCaptureObjects="$(DoNotAlterChangeDataCaptureObjects)"
      DoNotAlterReplicatedObjects="$(DoNotAlterReplicatedObjects)"
      DoNotDropAggregates="$(DoNotDropAggregates)"
      DoNotDropApplicationRoles="$(DoNotDropApplicationRoles)"
      DoNotDropAssemblies="$(DoNotDropAssemblies)"
      DoNotDropAsymmetricKeys="$(DoNotDropAsymmetricKeys)"
      DoNotDropAudits="$(DoNotDropAudits)"
      DoNotDropBrokerPriorities="$(DoNotDropBrokerPriorities)"
      DoNotDropCertificates="$(DoNotDropCertificates)"
      DoNotDropClrUserDefinedTypes="$(DoNotDropClrUserDefinedTypes)"
      DoNotDropColumnEncryptionKeys="$(DoNotDropColumnEncryptionKeys)"
      DoNotDropColumnMasterKeys="$(DoNotDropColumnMasterKeys)"
      DoNotDropContracts="$(DoNotDropContracts)"
      DoNotDropCredentials="$(DoNotDropCredentials)"
      DoNotDropCryptographicProviders="$(DoNotDropCryptographicProviders)"
      DoNotDropDatabaseAuditSpecifications="$(DoNotDropDatabaseAuditSpecifications)"
      DoNotDropDatabaseRoles="$(DoNotDropDatabaseRoles)"
      DoNotDropDatabaseScopedCredentials="$(DoNotDropDatabaseScopedCredentials)"
      DoNotDropDatabaseTriggers="$(DoNotDropDatabaseTriggers)"
      DoNotDropDefaults="$(DoNotDropDefaults)"
      DoNotDropEndpoints="$(DoNotDropEndpoints)"
      DoNotDropErrorMessages="$(DoNotDropErrorMessages)"
      DoNotDropEventNotifications="$(DoNotDropEventNotifications)"
      DoNotDropEventSessions="$(DoNotDropEventSessions)"
      DoNotDropExtendedProperties="$(DoNotDropExtendedProperties)"
      DoNotDropExternalDataSources="$(DoNotDropExternalDataSources)"
      DoNotDropExternalFileFormats="$(DoNotDropExternalFileFormats)"
      DoNotDropExternalTables="$(DoNotDropExternalTables)"
      DoNotDropFilegroups="$(DoNotDropFilegroups)"
      DoNotDropFileTables="$(DoNotDropFileTables)"
      DoNotDropFullTextCatalogs="$(DoNotDropFullTextCatalogs)"
      DoNotDropFullTextStoplists="$(DoNotDropFullTextStoplists)"
      DoNotDropLinkedServerLogins="$(DoNotDropLinkedServerLogins)"
      DoNotDropLinkedServers="$(DoNotDropLinkedServers)"
      DoNotDropLogins="$(DoNotDropLogins)"
      DoNotDropMessageTypes="$(DoNotDropMessageTypes)"
      DoNotDropPartitionFunctions="$(DoNotDropPartitionFunctions)"
      DoNotDropPartitionSchemes="$(DoNotDropPartitionSchemes)"
      DoNotDropPermissions="$(DoNotDropPermissions)"
      DoNotDropQueues="$(DoNotDropQueues)"
      DoNotDropRemoteServiceBindings="$(DoNotDropRemoteServiceBindings)"
      DoNotDropRoleMembership="$(DoNotDropRoleMembership)"
      DoNotDropRoutes="$(DoNotDropRoutes)"
      DoNotDropRules="$(DoNotDropRules)"
      DoNotDropScalarValuedFunctions="$(DoNotDropScalarValuedFunctions)"
      DoNotDropSearchPropertyLists="$(DoNotDropSearchPropertyLists)"
      DoNotDropSecurityPolicies="$(DoNotDropSecurityPolicies)"
      DoNotDropSequences="$(DoNotDropSequences)"
      DoNotDropServerAuditSpecifications="$(DoNotDropServerAuditSpecifications)"
      DoNotDropServerRoleMembership="$(DoNotDropServerRoleMembership)"
      DoNotDropServerRoles="$(DoNotDropServerRoles)"
      DoNotDropServerTriggers="$(DoNotDropServerTriggers)"
      DoNotDropServices="$(DoNotDropServices)"
      DoNotDropSignatures="$(DoNotDropSignatures)"
      DoNotDropStoredProcedures="$(DoNotDropStoredProcedures)"
      DoNotDropSymmetricKeys="$(DoNotDropSymmetricKeys)"
      DoNotDropSynonyms="$(DoNotDropSynonyms)"
      DoNotDropTables="$(DoNotDropTables)"
      DoNotDropTableValuedFunctions="$(DoNotDropTableValuedFunctions)"
      DoNotDropUserDefinedDataTypes="$(DoNotDropUserDefinedDataTypes)"
      DoNotDropUserDefinedTableTypes="$(DoNotDropUserDefinedTableTypes)"
      DoNotDropUsers="$(DoNotDropUsers)"
      DoNotDropViews="$(DoNotDropViews)"
      DoNotDropXmlSchemaCollections="$(DoNotDropXmlSchemaCollections)"
      DropConstraintsNotInSource="$(DropConstraintsNotInSource)"
      DropDmlTriggersNotInSource="$(DropDmlTriggersNotInSource)"
      DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource="$(DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource)"
      DropIndexesNotInSource="$(DropIndexesNotInSource)"
      DropObjectsNotInSource="$(DropObjectsNotInSource)"
      DropPermissionsNotInSource="$(DropPermissionsNotInSource)"
      DropRoleMembersNotInSource="$(DropRoleMembersNotInSource)"
      DropStatisticsNotInSource="$(DropStatisticsNotInSource)"
      ExcludeAggregates="$(ExcludeAggregates)"
      ExcludeApplicationRoles="$(ExcludeApplicationRoles)"
      ExcludeAssemblies="$(ExcludeAssemblies)"
      ExcludeAsymmetricKeys="$(ExcludeAsymmetricKeys)"
      ExcludeAudits="$(ExcludeAudits)"
      ExcludeBrokerPriorities="$(ExcludeBrokerPriorities)"
      ExcludeCertificates="$(ExcludeCertificates)"
      ExcludeClrUserDefinedTypes="$(ExcludeClrUserDefinedTypes)"
      ExcludeColumnEncryptionKeys="$(ExcludeColumnEncryptionKeys)"
      ExcludeColumnMasterKeys="$(ExcludeColumnMasterKeys)"
      ExcludeContracts="$(ExcludeContracts)"
      ExcludeCredentials="$(ExcludeCredentials)"
      ExcludeCryptographicProviders="$(ExcludeCryptographicProviders)"
      ExcludeDatabaseAuditSpecifications="$(ExcludeDatabaseAuditSpecifications)"
      ExcludeDatabaseRoles="$(ExcludeDatabaseRoles)"
      ExcludeDatabaseScopedCredentials="$(ExcludeDatabaseScopedCredentials)"
      ExcludeDatabaseTriggers="$(ExcludeDatabaseTriggers)"
      ExcludeDefaults="$(ExcludeDefaults)"
      ExcludeEndpoints="$(ExcludeEndpoints)"
      ExcludeErrorMessages="$(ExcludeErrorMessages)"
      ExcludeEventNotifications="$(ExcludeEventNotifications)"
      ExcludeEventSessions="$(ExcludeEventSessions)"
      ExcludeExternalDataSources="$(ExcludeExternalDataSources)"
      ExcludeExternalFileFormats="$(ExcludeExternalFileFormats)"
      ExcludeExternalTables="$(ExcludeExternalTables)"
      ExcludeFilegroups="$(ExcludeFilegroups)"
      ExcludeFileTables="$(ExcludeFileTables)"
      ExcludeFullTextCatalogs="$(ExcludeFullTextCatalogs)"
      ExcludeFullTextStoplists="$(ExcludeFullTextStoplists)"
      ExcludeLinkedServerLogins="$(ExcludeLinkedServerLogins)"
      ExcludeLinkedServers="$(ExcludeLinkedServers)"
      ExcludeLogins="$(ExcludeLogins)"
      ExcludeMessageTypes="$(ExcludeMessageTypes)"
      ExcludePartitionFunctions="$(ExcludePartitionFunctions)"
      ExcludePartitionSchemes="$(ExcludePartitionSchemes)"
      ExcludeQueues="$(ExcludeQueues)"
      ExcludeRemoteServiceBindings="$(ExcludeRemoteServiceBindings)"
      ExcludeRoutes="$(ExcludeRoutes)"
      ExcludeRules="$(ExcludeRules)"
      ExcludeScalarValuedFunctions="$(ExcludeScalarValuedFunctions)"
      ExcludeSearchPropertyLists="$(ExcludeSearchPropertyLists)"
      ExcludeSecurityPolicies="$(ExcludeSecurityPolicies)"
      ExcludeSequences="$(ExcludeSequences)"
      ExcludeServerAuditSpecifications="$(ExcludeServerAuditSpecifications)"
      ExcludeServerRoleMembership="$(ExcludeServerRoleMembership)"
      ExcludeServerRoles="$(ExcludeServerRoles)"
      ExcludeServerTriggers="$(ExcludeServerTriggers)"
      ExcludeServices="$(ExcludeServices)"
      ExcludeSignatures="$(ExcludeSignatures)"
      ExcludeStoredProcedures="$(ExcludeStoredProcedures)"
      ExcludeSymmetricKeys="$(ExcludeSymmetricKeys)"
      ExcludeSynonyms="$(ExcludeSynonyms)"
      ExcludeTables="$(ExcludeTables)"
      ExcludeTableValuedFunctions="$(ExcludeTableValuedFunctions)"
      ExcludeUserDefinedDataTypes="$(ExcludeUserDefinedDataTypes)"
      ExcludeUserDefinedTableTypes="$(ExcludeUserDefinedTableTypes)"
      ExcludeUsers="$(ExcludeUsers)"
      ExcludeViews="$(ExcludeViews)"
      ExcludeXmlSchemaCollections="$(ExcludeXmlSchemaCollections)"
      GenerateSmartDefaults="$(GenerateSmartDefaults)"
      IgnoreAnsiNulls="$(IgnoreAnsiNulls)"
      IgnoreAuthorizer="$(IgnoreAuthorizer)"
      IgnoreColumnCollation="$(IgnoreColumnCollation)"
      IgnoreComments="$(IgnoreComments)"
      IgnoreCryptographicProviderFilePath="$(IgnoreCryptographicProviderFilePath)"
      IgnoreDdlTriggerOrder="$(IgnoreDdlTriggerOrder)"
      IgnoreDdlTriggerState="$(IgnoreDdlTriggerState)"
      IgnoreDefaultSchema="$(IgnoreDefaultSchema)"
      IgnoreDmlTriggerOrder="$(IgnoreDmlTriggerOrder)"
      IgnoreDmlTriggerState="$(IgnoreDmlTriggerState)"
      IgnoreExtendedProperties="$(IgnoreExtendedProperties)"
      IgnoreFileAndLogFilePath="$(IgnoreFileAndLogFilePath)"
      IgnoreFilegroupPlacement="$(IgnoreFilegroupPlacement)"
      IgnoreFileSize="$(IgnoreFileSize)"
      IgnoreFillFactor="$(IgnoreFillFactor)"
      IgnoreFullTextCatalogFilePath="$(IgnoreFullTextCatalogFilePath)"
      IgnoreIdentitySeed="$(IgnoreIdentitySeed)"
      IgnoreIncrement="$(IgnoreIncrement)"
      IgnoreIndexOptions="$(IgnoreIndexOptions)"
      IgnoreIndexPadding="$(IgnoreIndexPadding)"
      IgnoreKeywordCasing="$(IgnoreKeywordCasing)"
      IgnoreLockHintsOnIndexes="$(IgnoreLockHintsOnIndexes)"
      IgnoreLoginSids="$(IgnoreLoginSids)"
      IgnoreNotForReplication="$(IgnoreNotForReplication)"
      IgnoreObjectPlacementOnPartitionScheme="$(IgnoreObjectPlacementOnPartitionScheme)"
      IgnorePartitionSchemes="$(IgnorePartitionSchemes)"
      IgnorePermissions="$(IgnorePermissions)"
      IgnoreQuotedIdentifiers="$(IgnoreQuotedIdentifiers)"
      IgnoreRoleMembership="$(IgnoreRoleMembership)"
      IgnoreRouteLifetime="$(IgnoreRouteLifetime)"
      IgnoreSemicolonBetweenStatements="$(IgnoreSemicolonBetweenStatements)"
      IgnoreTableOptions="$(IgnoreTableOptions)"
      IgnoreUserSettingsObjects="$(IgnoreUserSettingsObjects)"
      IgnoreWhitespace="$(IgnoreWhitespace)"
      IgnoreWithNocheckOnCheckConstraints="$(IgnoreWithNocheckOnCheckConstraints)"
      IgnoreWithNocheckOnForeignKeys="$(IgnoreWithNocheckOnForeignKeys)"
      IncludeCompositeObjects="$(IncludeCompositeObjects)"
      IncludeTransactionalScripts="$(IncludeTransactionalScripts)"
      NoAlterStatementsToChangeCLRTypes="$(NoAlterStatementsToChangeCLRTypes)"
      PopulateFilesOnFileGroups="$(PopulateFilesOnFileGroups)"
      RegisterDataTierApplication="$(RegisterDataTierApplication)"
      ScriptDatabaseCollation="$(ScriptDatabaseCollation)"
      ScriptDatabaseCompatibility="$(ScriptDatabaseCompatibility)"
      ScriptDatabaseOptions="$(ScriptDatabaseOptions)"
      ScriptDeployStateChecks="$(ScriptDeployStateChecks)"
      ScriptFileSize="$(ScriptFileSize)"
      ScriptNewConstraintValidation="$(ScriptNewConstraintValidation)"
      ScriptRefreshModule="$(ScriptRefreshModule)"
      TargetDatabaseName="$(TargetDatabaseName)"
      TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings="$(TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings)"
      UnmodifiableObjectWarnings="$(UnmodifiableObjectWarnings)"
      VerifyCollationCompatibility="$(VerifyCollationCompatibility)"
      VerifyDeployment="$(VerifyDeployment)"
      >
      <Output TaskParameter="IntermediateFileWrites" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </SqlBuildTask>

On our previous sprint, the build and deploy of the project was working fine. When I did a TFS compare with the previous version there are no major differences.
```

This is what I have done already:

- I have upgraded SSDT to the most recent version (didn't fix it)
- deleted the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets file and repair the ssdt instalation (didn't fix it either)

I am still looking for any duplicated keys in the targets file as the exception points out

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I just close and restart the VS 2017 and it works.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to have happened because the refactorlog file (which contains information about renaming of columns) contained two or more entries with the same ChangeDateTime value.  There is a bug in how SSDT handles these duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete everything except the files starting with ".NET" in the following folder:

```
...\UserAccountUsedByTfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp
```

That did it!

Answer (score 0):

1. I did this by deleting Temp Folder of Local System
2. Check in Visual Studio 2017 - SSDT Project - Schema Compare File is opened
3. If open then close the same and restart the Visual Studio 2017
4. It Works for Me - Now Build Successfull

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I just close and restart my VS 2022 and it works